# model makeham using nls with 2 categorical variables

Tags: r, nls

I want to use nls to do a model makeham with 2 categorical variables, with just 1 variable it works.

For example,

```
# Create the data
df <- data.frame(edad  = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35),
                  maduraciongrp = c("0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+", "0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+", "0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+","0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+", "0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+", "0-1", "0-1", "2", "2", "3+", "3+"),
                  origen = c("0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1"),
                  expuestos = sample(100:500, 36),
                 dec = sample(1:90, 36)
                  )

df <- df %>% mutate(mx=dec/expuestos, maduraciongrp=maduraciongrp %>% as.factor())

# craete model gompertz to obtain b0 and b1
gompertz<-nls(mx ~exp(b0 + b1 * edad), start =list(b0 =1,b1 =0),weights = expuestos, data= df)

# Create model makeham with 1 categorical variable
makeham1<-nls(mx ~  a[maduraciongrp] + exp(b0 + b1 * edad), data= df,  
             start =list(b0 =coef(gompertz)[1],b1 =coef(gompertz)[2], a=rep(0, nlevels(df$maduraciongrp))), 
             weights =expuestos)
```

Now I want to include other categorical variable and I'm using the following code

```
makeham1<-nls(mx ~  a[maduraciongrp] + b[origen] + exp(b0 + b1 * edad), data= df,  
              start =list(b0 =coef(gompertz)[1],b1 =coef(gompertz)[2], a=rep(0, nlevels(df$maduraciongrp)),
              b=rep(0, 2)), weights =expuestos)
```

but appears the following error

```
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

How can I include the second categorical variable to my model?

Comment: I am having trouble getting the first model to work correctly.  But in the second model, try having "Origen" as a factor and not character string.

Comment: I try but didn't work